# How to use apply() on a user defined function in r - error saying it's not a function

Tags: r, apply, user-defined-functions

I've written a function that calculates the density of a bivariate normal distribution using the width and length of flowers. I want to apply the function to a data frame to calculate the density for each row. I'm trying to use the apply() function to do this but it's giving me an error saying my function isn't a function. My function does work when I use it for a single row so I don't think it's a problem with the function itself. I tried looking into it but couldn't find much on how to implement a user defined function in apply(). Here is my code with some sample data.

```
density_fn<- function(x, y, mu_x, mu_y, sigma){
  mean_vec<- matrix(c((x - mu_x), (y - mu_y)))
  sigma_det<- det(sigma)
  sigma_inv<- solve(sigma)
  frac<- 1/(2*pi*sqrt(sigma_det))
  exponent<- exp(-0.5%*%t(mean_vec)%*%sigma_inv%*%mean_vec)
  den_fn<- frac*exponent
  return(den_fn)
}

flower<- data.frame(
  Width = c(20, 32, 29),
  Length = c( 51, 66, 48)
)
flower_w_mean<- 27
flower_l_mean<- 55
cov_matrix<- matrix(c(39, 0, 0, 93), nrow=2, ncol=2) 

apply(flower, 1, FUN = density_fn(flower$Width, flower$Length, 
                            flower_w_mean, flower_l_mean, cov_matrix))
```

Originally, I got this error:

> Error in -0.5 % * % t(mean_vec) % * % sigma_inv : non-conformable arguments

I thought it was an issue with my covariance matrix, so I took out everything but the first line of the function and returned `mean_vec` and that's when I got this error:

> Error in match.fun(FUN) :
> c("'density_fn(flower$Width, flower$Length, flower_w_mean, flower_l_mean, ' is not a function, character or symbol", "'    cov_matrix)' is not a function, character or symbol")

Anyone know how to properly apply this function to a data frame?

Comment: The first error you are encountering is from this line `exponent<- exp(-0.5%*%t(mean_vec)%*%sigma_inv%*%mean_vec)`. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me explain two error messages that you got.

**The first error**

> Error in -0.5 % * % t(mean_vec) % * % sigma_inv : non-conformable arguments

This error message shows that the cause of the error is the multiplication of arguments not conformable to the rule. The rule of the matrix multiplication `A %*% B` is that the number of column(s) of `A` if it's a matrix, or the length of `A` if it's a vector,  has to equal the number of row(s) of `B`.

In `density_fn` the definition `mean_vec<- matrix(c((x - mu_x), (y - mu_y)))` makes `mean_vec` a matrix that has exactly **1** column and the number of rows equal to the total length of `x` combined with `y`. Consequently, if the number of rows of `sigma_inv` **> 1**,
the matrix multiplication  `t(mean_vec) %*% sigma_inv` doesn't conform to the rule and will result in error.  For example:

```
x <- 1:2  # length of 2
y <- 1:3 # length of 3 
sigma <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)
sigma_inv <- solve(sigma)
mean_vec <- matrix(c(x - mean(x), y - mean(y))) 
mean_vec # 1 row 5 columns
#     [,1]
#[1,] -0.5
#[2,]  0.5
#[3,] -1.0
#[4,]  0.0
#[5,]  1.0

t(mean_vec) %*% sigma_inv
# Error in t(mean_vec) %*% sigma_inv : non-conformable arguments
```

It will not result in error if each of `x` and `y` has the length of 1. That's why this function does work when you use it for a single row. For example:

```
x <- 2  # length of 1
y <- 3 # length of 1 
sigma <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)
mean_vec <- matrix(c(x - mean(x), y - mean(y))) 
sigma_inv <- solve(sigma)
t(mean_vec) %*% sigma_inv
#     [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    0
```

An alternative way to get the function to work properly for any length of `x` and `y` is to set the number of row and the number of column in `mean_vec <- matrix()` as follows:

```
mean_vec <- matrix(c((x - mu_x), (y - mu_y)), 
                     ncol = nrow(sigma), 
                     nrow = ncol(sigma))
```

and then to change the matrix multiplication `-0.5 %*% mean_vec` to a scalar  multiplication `-0.5 * mean_vec`.

So, the function becomes:

```
density_fn <- function(x, y, mu_x, mu_y, sigma) {
  mean_vec <- matrix(c((x - mu_x), (y - mu_y)), 
                     ncol = nrow(sigma), 
                     nrow = ncol(sigma))
  sigma_det <- det(sigma)
  sigma_inv <- solve(sigma)
  frac <- 1 / (2 * pi * sqrt(sigma_det))
  exponent <- exp(-0.5 * t(mean_vec) %*% sigma_inv %*% mean_vec)
  den_fn <- frac * exponent
  return(den_fn)
}
```

**The second error**

> Error in match.fun(FUN) : c("'density_fn(flower$Width, flower$Length,
> flower_w_mean, flower_l_mean, ' is not a function, character or
> symbol", "' cov_matrix)' is not a function, character or symbol")

This error message shows that the value of `FUN` in `apply` is not properly specified. According to the documentation of `apply`, the value to be assigned to `FUN` should be

> typically is either a function or a symbol (e.g., a backquoted name)
> or a character string specifying a function to be searched for from
> the environment of the call to apply

It means you should mention **only** the function name to `FUN`. The additional arguments of the function (the 2nd argument, the 3rd one,...) should be mentioned after `FUN`, not within `FUN`. Please check `?apply` for details.

However, this step alone does not solve the problem because `apply` is suitable for a univariate input. Because your input is multivariate, `mapply` is more suitable. Other options include `Map` and loops using `for` etc.

**How to apply functions using `mapply`**

It is best explained by a simple example. Please check `?mapply` for details. Suppose you have `x` and `y` and you want to get `z = 2x + 3y`. You want to vectorize the function to `x` and `y`.

```
x <- c(3,4,5)
y <- c(10,20, 30)
myfun <- function(x,y) 2*x + 3*y
z <- mapply(myfun, x, y)
z
#[1]  36  68 100
```

If you have arguments other than `x` and `y` in `myfun`, you should assign them to `MoreArgs`. Here is the example using `density_fn`.

```
mapply(density_fn, x = flower$Width, y = flower$Length, MoreArgs = list(
                                            mu_x = flower_w_mean, 
                                            mu_y = flower_l_mean, 
                                            sigma = cov_matrix))
#         [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
# [1,] 0.001293784 0.001000747 0.001929141
# [2,] 0.001293784 0.001000747 0.001929141
# [3,] 0.001293784 0.001000747 0.001929141
# [4,] 0.001293784 0.001000747 0.001929141
```

These steps do not produce errors. However, because of my limited knowledge on the subject, I do not guarantee that these steps properly represent the density function of bivariate normal distribution as you intended.